# Not able to install latest version of mongo-go-driver (v1.2.1)

Tags: mongodb, go, dep, mongo-go

I am not able to get v1.2.1 for mongo-go-driver. I am using dep to resolve dependency. 
My import block looks like-

```
import (
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
  "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"

  "fmt"
  "context"
)
```

When I am running `dep ensure -v` I get following output

```
(50)  ✗   github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver at v1.2.1 has problem subpkg(s):
(50)        github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/objectid is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/private/cluster is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/readpref has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/writeconcern has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.  github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/decimal is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/elements is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/connstring is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/options has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/private/ops is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/readconcern has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.
(49)      try github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver@v1.2.0
(50)  ✗   github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver at v1.2.0 has problem subpkg(s):
(50)        github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/objectid is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/options has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/readconcern has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/elements is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/decimal is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/connstring is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/private/cluster is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/private/ops is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/readpref has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/writeconcern has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.
(49)      try github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver@v1.1.4
(50)  ✗   github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver at v1.1.4 has problem subpkg(s):
(50)        github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/private/cluster is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/private/ops is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/readconcern has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/readpref has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/writeconcern has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/connstring is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/decimal is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/elements is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/objectid is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.    github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/options has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1. github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson has err (*pkgtree.NonCanonicalImportRoot); required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.

.
.
.


(49)      try github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver@v0.0.2
(50)  ✗   github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver at v0.0.2 has problem subpkg(s):
(50)        github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo/options is missing; required by go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v0.0.1.
(49)      try github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver@v0.0.1
(49)  ✓ select github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver@v0.0.1 w/20 pkgs
```

And it imports v.0.0.1 at the end. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved. Here is the solution for anyone else facing the issue.
Add the following lines to `Gopkg.toml`

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver"
  version = "~1.2.0"
```

You can replace version value to your required version.